# ios In-App Purchase In-App Purchase transactionReceipt validation

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

After successful purchase my app sends the transactionReceipt  to server so that it is validated using `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.` .

Now i does the following.

1. store the key in db
2. if the status received is 0 php script add the sucbscription to the
   user.
3. expire the key.,up to this its ok but he problem now is

if the user somehow submit the transactionReceipt which he has used for some other purchase and sent to our server .it also validate true if posted to  `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` so he gets another subscription for free .
**please help to solve this issue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a documentation about this issue [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html).

basically the verifyReceipt respond holds a `receipt` field with data about the original transaction. you need to check this data if it belongs to the right purchase and make sure, the customer does not get the purchase twice.

Comment: i have already read that ..actually any receipt of any valid purchase validates .so how come i know it is from my app the purchase has happend..

Comment: They even provide [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html)

Comment: they say how to validate key but they don't say how to validate the origin of transaction, from which app transaction started.

Comment: the receipt data has `app_item_id`, `product_id` and `transaction_id`, your server should know this, don't he? and how secure is the connection between your app and your server?

Comment: we use tls (https) so there is no man in middle attack or something like that.but this app_item_id, product_id and transaction_id will be also for some other application for some other purchase also .if the user of app submit details of some other purchase then also itunes validate  the purchase key.

Comment: your server knows which app_id and product_id combination is valid for this particular transaction. it doesn't matter what itunes validation says if it has the wrong app_id.

Comment: the purchase happens in iphone app the purchase key is sent to the server for validation and adding  magazine subscriptions to the user.

Comment: maybe i still don't get your problem. i understand that you have several magazine applications which all use the same server. one app purchases something and send the transaction data to your server. this server then verifies the transaction data and enables the subscription for this **app and user** in your database. if it is already enabled, nothing happens. what did i miss?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17113/discussion-between-arun-killu-and-jan-prieser)